# The app bundle must contain app icon for iPad

Tags: icons, app-store-connect

After successfully submission of my app to app store.
i got one metadata reject after solving it, its not submitting for review showing "the app bundle must contain app icon for iPad". 
Now how to resolve it ,thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem is very likely the 167x167 iPad Pro icon. I have exactly the same problem since around 2 weeks. After adding this icon the submission succeeds.

Comment: I do not have option in info.plist to upload the 167x167 ipad pro icon.I have submitted my app that time it did not show any error ,after two days its asking .Now do i need to create new iPa?

Answer (score 1):

The icon sizes for iPad are not the same as iPhone ones, so just add icons with the right resolution.

According to [Apple Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html), you need a **76x76** icon (normal display), a **152x152** (retina display) and **167x167** for iPad Pro.

Comment: These things has been done and application was hosted for review 5days back.Now how to add icon for iPad in the same version.

Comment: If you bundle was invalid then your only choice is to create a new one and wait for the "waiting for review" again.